# Does drupal_add_css not load duplicate filenames by design?

Tags: 7, theming

If I try to add a css file using drupal_add_css to a custom module where there is already a css file loaded with the same name elsewhere (in my case in the theme, based on Zen), the module version does not load at all. Nothing to do with overriding styles - the two files contain completely different style information. If I change the filename in the custom module to something else which does not conflict, it loads correctly.

The question is is this by design? If not, is it a known bug? In my opinion this should not happen as a module developer has no idea what css files will be called in any custom theme.

Comment: I think there's some kind of guidelines that you should name your css and javascript files with your module name as a prefix. Something like `modulename_styles.css` or `modulename_scripts.js`

Comment: Yes someone else has just informed me of this. I suppose this could still be an issue if the theme and module have the same name... unlucky but possible. Thanks

Comment: If your module and theme have the same name, you will be having much bigger problems than just overridden stylesheets.

Comment: @sheena_d Is it really beyond the realms of possibility that you have a theme called, for example, Awesome and a module called Awesome, thereby having the same prefix? You might not create one or the other to conflict with a module/theme you have but if you make it publicly available you can't guarantee to not clash with any existing theme/module surely. I'm being devil's advocate a bit here I admit.

Comment: You could have a theme called `awesome_theme` and a module called `awesome_module`, but if both the theme and module are named `awesome`, you will run the risk of conflicts within Drupal core and within your theme and module when calling hooks, etc. As for not being able to "guarantee to not clash with any existing theme/module," drupal.org will not let two projects (independent of type) exist with the same name. It is definitely possible for a module and theme to exist in a site with the same name, I have done it before. Once. Then I learned the hard way that doing this can cause problems.

Comment: I did not know about the name check regardless of project type. Makes sense. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) function, it seems this behaviour is by design.

For any CSS that you add using the function *without* using 'inline' as an argument, the array of files is keyed by the first argument (string) that you pass in. So if you were to run:

```
drupal_add_css('file.css');
```

And another module has also called `drupal_add_css()` with the same file name, the original will be overwritten.

As Marius Illie mentions in a comment above, the best way to avoid this is to prefix any CSS files you add with your module name.

Comment: Yes a module prefix seems to be the accepted way of avoiding this. Thanks.